# Finding a bi-partition in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, graph

How can I find a bi-partition in polynomial time in the size of input(n, the number of vertices)? Is it possible? The number of vertices must remain the same and you can delete as few edges as possible.
Does polynomial time mean O(n), O(n^2) or just O(n)?

I would have done a BFS putting nodes in two different sets but the complexity would have been O(V+E) and this is not what I want to.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: polynomial time means `n^[some positive real]`. So even O(n^10000000) is polynomial time.

Comment: O(V+E) is considered polynomial time.

Comment: I fail to see how deleting as few edges as possible isn't the same as solving the clique problem (which is NP complete).

Comment: It actually says "polynomial time with regard to the number of vertices". Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Optimal solution is typically [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition) but plenty of polynomial heuristics exist. Take a look at [Kernighan-Lin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernighan%E2%80%93Lin_algorithm) for a simple alorithm.

If you're trying to solve a real-world problem as opposed to homework, you might be better off searching for a pre-existing partitioner. There are many libraries available particularly in the METIS family.

Comment: We haven't got that far. It's a simple digraph without any costs. I just want to traverse the nodes, coloring the odd levels with green and the even levels with blue. And if I find an edge between two nodes of the same level I'll remove it or something. How can this be NP?

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru Costs don't change the problem that much. Edge directions can be ignored (anyway those would make the problem *more* complicated). It is the minimization part which is hard. Because every potential removal gives you a completely different new graph to analyze, you have an exponential number of solutions to consider before finding the best one.

Comment: Ah... O.K. So, if I want to find a regular solution, not the best one, is bfs suitable for this? How can I prove that the number of edges of my bi-partition >= than the number of original graph's edges / 4?

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru If that's your criterion for an acceptable solution, you should have mentioned it in the first place. Anyway, not every graph has such a solution; for example to partition any graph with two nodes you must remove all the edges. Obviously there's still a lot you're not telling us.

Comment: I don't understand, if you partition a graph with two nodes and you remove the only edge it exists, 0 won't be >= than 1/4, is it? I thought this criterion means that I have to keep as many edges as I can that's why I said I need to delete as few edges as possible. Obviously, it isn't the same thing.

Comment: And, actually, I made a post a few hours ago where I presented the whole problem and nobody answered so I thought breaking it into pieces would make it more approachable. The requirement is to prove that, for a graph with at least 2 nodes, you can build a bi-partition in polynomial time so that its number of edges >= than graph's edges / 4.

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru Make sure the pieces are self-contained! "At least 2 nodes" means that the number of nodes can be 2, which as I mentioned requires removing all the edges. Otherwise you should be OK, but that problem is completely different from the one you asked here.

Comment: I don't see the other problem; could you link? Anyway you might ask on [Math.SE].

Comment: Hmm, I think the algorithm is simply to find the node of lowest degree (in O(V) time) and remove all its edges (in O(E) time). To show there are enough other edges left, use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma .

Comment: Oh... I removed it. I'm not sure you're allowed to have two similar posts with the same tag. As I said I don't think I have to remove anything if the number of nodes is two.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40550/discussion-between-carmen-cojocaru-and-potatoswatter)